# Почему обрезает изображение?

Tags: html, css

При медиа запросе на адаптив:

```css
/*Reviews - Slider*/
.section--top{
 margin-top: -80px;
}
.reviews{
 position: relative;
}

.reviews .slick-slider{
 padding: 0px 70px;
}

.reviews__item{
 min-height: 210px; 
 padding-left: 260px;
 position: relative;
}
.reviews__photo{
 display: block;
 width: 210px;
 height: 210px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.reviews__text{
 font: 300 italic 24px/1.5 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.reviews__author{
 font: 400 24px 'Kaushan Script', sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.reviews__author:before{
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 60px;
 height: 3px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #f38181;
}

.slick-arrow{
 font-size: 0;
 color: transparent;

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1;

 border: 0;
  background: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-arrow:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

.slick-arrow:after{
 content:"";
 display: block;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;

 border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.slick-prev{
 left: 0;
 transform:  rotate(-135deg);
}

.slick-next{
 right: 0;
 transform:  rotate(45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px){
 .reviews__text{
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .reviews__photo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
 }
 .reviews__item{
  padding-left: 190px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
 .section--gray{
  padding: 50px 0;
 }
 .reviews__photo{
  position: static;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 150px;
 }
 .reviews__item{
  padding-left: 0;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
 .reviews .slick-slider{
  padding: 0px 25px;
 }
 .reviews__author{
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 .slick-arrow{
  top: 18%;
 }
}
```

```html
<section class="section section--top">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="reviews">
   
   <div data-slider>
    <div> 
     <div class="reviews__item">
      <img class="reviews__photo" src="img/works/human.png" alt="">
      <div class="reviews__text">
       <p>
        “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="reviews__author">Jon Doe</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 

  </div><!--/reviews -->

 </div><!--</container-->
</section>
```

Изображение вставлено в Slick-Slider может он обрезает? Как исправить?
Тут нормально http://prntscr.com/r2oiil 
a тут обрезает
 http://prntscr.com/r2o8mp

Comment: вставил весь код данной секции.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема скорее всего здесь `translateY(-15%);`

Для моб версии сделайте так

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){   
    .reviews__photo{
        position: static;
        transform: translateY(0); // делаем равным 0
        margin: 0 auto 15px auto; // делаем отступ снизу 15px
        min-height: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет не то, там все норм. Разобрался, перебивают классы самого Slick-slider он не скачан а подключен по сdn вот скрин свойства которое перебивает http://prntscr.com/r2p16d 
Как только его перебить своими стилями? Пробовал так:
.reviews .click-list{
  overflow-y:visible ;
}
не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понимаю вопрос, то так должно быть?

ps Поспешил дать ответ и не обратил внимание, @soledar10 правильно уже написал. Дело в этом:

> Для мобильной версии пропишите
>
> @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
>       .section--top{
>           margin-top: 0;
>       } }

translateY(-15%); здесь не причем.

```css
/*Reviews - Slider*/
.reviews{
 position: relative;
}

.reviews .slick-slider{
 padding: 0px 70px;
}

.reviews__item{
 min-height: 210px; 
 padding-left: 260px;
 position: relative;
}
.reviews__photo{
 display: block;
 width: 210px;
 height: 210px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.reviews__text{
 font: 300 italic 24px/1.5 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.reviews__author{
 font: 400 24px 'Kaushan Script', sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.reviews__author:before{
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 60px;
 height: 3px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #f38181;
}

.slick-arrow{
 font-size: 0;
 color: transparent;

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1;

 border: 0;
  background: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-arrow:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

.slick-arrow:after{
 content:"";
 display: block;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;

 border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.slick-prev{
 left: 0;
 transform:  rotate(-135deg);
}

.slick-next{
 right: 0;
 transform:  rotate(45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px){
 .reviews__text{
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .reviews__photo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
 }
 .reviews__item{
  padding-left: 190px;
 }
.section--top{
 margin-top: -80px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
 .section--gray{
  padding: 50px 0;
 }
 .reviews__photo{
  position: static;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 150px;
 }
 .reviews__item{
  padding-left: 0;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
 .reviews .slick-slider{
  padding: 0px 25px;
 }
 .reviews__author{
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 .slick-arrow{
  top: 18%;
 }
}
```

```html
<section class="section section--top">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="reviews">
   
   <div data-slider>
    <div> 
     <div class="reviews__item">
      <img class="reviews__photo" src="img/works/human.png" alt="">
      <div class="reviews__text">
       <p>
        “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="reviews__author">Jon Doe</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 

  </div><!--/reviews -->

 </div><!--</container-->
</section>
```

Comment: Нет там перебивает стили слайдер вот http://prntscr.com/r2p16d вопрос как теперь отменить overflow:hidden; т.е перебить соими стилями чтобы не скачивать слайдер и не менять стили в его файле

Comment: перебил стили таким свойством:
.slick-list {
    overflow: visible;
но мне нужно сделать visible только по -y иначе тогда вылазит на всю ширину слайдер http://prntscr.com/r2r26a Разве нельзя отдельно сделать так 
     overflow-y: visible; ? Почему-то не работает.